# Google library with helper function for prop lookup at arbitrary depth?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

At my last job, I remember a file with lots of google helper functions, but I'm not sure if it was part of closure or some other library

The function I'm curious about is one which takes a string path "some.location.in.object" and either returns the value or null, without having to check if every object in the path exists

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I'm curious what the library was called with all of the useful helper functions. I vaguely remember the prefix being `goog.`

Thanks

Comment: That would block renaming. I wouldn't expect it to be a part of closure library.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth it is, see http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.html#getObjectByName

Comment: I see it carries a long list of warnings to. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The library is `closure-library/closure/goog/base.js` and function is `getObjectByName`

See http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.html#getObjectByName

Comment: Make sure to note the warnings given by the description: this is designed only for use for external namespaces. If used on internal source with `ADVANCED` mode, you will end up with broken code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of `goog.provide` and `goog.require` which define and find a namespace object. See http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.html

> In addition, goog.provide() creates the object stubs for a namespace (for example, goog.provide("goog.foo.bar") will create the object goog.foo.bar if it does not already exist).

Probably not what you are after, but `goog.array` has a lot of very useful "functional programming" code.  See http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.array.html